# iOS Core Data - Add related data to entity

Tags: ios, core-data

iOS beginner here.

Given an entity with a Many-to-Many relationship

```
@class Categories;

@interface Events : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *categories;
@end

@interface Events (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCategoriesObject:(Categories *)value;
- (void)removeCategoriesObject:(Categories *)value;
- (void)addCategories:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCategories:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Which is related to

```
@interface Categories : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *events;

@end
```

And having some JSON data to populate the Events table

```
[{"title": "Test Exhibition", "categories": [{"name": "Exhibitions"}]}, {...}]
```

How should I format the JSON data to do something like

```
// Parse Events JSON
[events enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
...
Events *event = [NSEntityDescription
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Events" inManagedObjectContext:context];
event.title = [obj objectForKey:@"title"];
NSSet *categories = [[[NSSet alloc] init] setByAddingObjectsFromArray:[obj objectForKey:@"categories"]];
NSLog(@"CATS %@", categories);
[event addCategories:categories];
```

to eventually get Core Data to find the relative Category (already added to the database) and attach it to the Event?

At the moment I get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x893a8c0'
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Whenever you get an `unrecognized selector` error, always use the debugger to check whether the object your are sending a message to is of the type you expect it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`categories` is an `NSSet` of `NSDictionaries`, but

```
- (void)addCategories:(NSSet *)values;
```

expects an `NSSet` of `NSManagedObject's`. So, you have to create an `NSManagedObject` from each dictionary that describes a category, add them to a new `NSSet` (or `NSMutableSet`) and only then call `addCategories:` with the new set.

Comment: So there's no other way than doing a fetch request to find the relevant Category (or add a new one) while looping through the Events?

Comment: That's right. You can minimize the number of hits to the persistent store by querying categories in batches. Please see section titled "Importing Efficiently" at [Importing Large Data Sets](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data.html). If you do it this way you'll have one query for categories per each event.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction and helping me realising it's down to Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html